# Locally stored files in application directory being randomly deleted on iPad, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My application on the iPad allows users to browse remote photos on their photo sharing site and optionally download whole albums of photos to the application's local directory (Documents) for offline viewing.  I'm running into a problem where after a user has downloaded several (large) videos for offline viewing, they come back later and find that the video doesn't exist locally anymore, this is perhaps 1-2GB of data.  They didn't remove it (which I allow them to), does Apple delete documents in 3rd party application directories?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious. What is the name of you app? Is it in the AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupidly using absolute paths instead of relative paths :p

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on how much space each app may take up. I haven't ever seen any official information on this, but everyone seems to agree that 2 GB is the limit. If you exceed that, the device will start deleting stuff.

Comment: I've heard of the 2GB limit as well but I thought this was a 2GB limit for install size of your app.  I guess you could conclude that also applies to the size of the app ever, hrm.

Comment: Yes, the discussions I've heard were exclusively about how much space you are allowed to use in files and such that you store yourself. I don't think anyone out there has ever done anything close to a 2 GB app, except WIRED who got close (~600 MBs).